# Why in Django the post method considers an empty form and returns the code 200?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

> When the blank form is sent. Instead of skipping the conditions and rendering the same form. Instead, it returns an empty form and gives code 200

```
   class ContactView(View):
        def get(self, request):
            form = ContactModelForm()
            return render(request, 'contact/contact_us.html', {'forms': form})

        def post(self, request):
            if request.method == 'POST':
               form = ContactModelForm(request.POST)
               if form.is_valid():
                  form.save()
                  return redirect('home')
           form = ContactModelForm()
           return render(request, 'contact/contact_us.html', {'forms': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only construct a new form in the GET case, so:

```
class ContactView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = ContactModelForm()
        return render(request, 'contact/contact_us.html', {'forms': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = ContactModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        # form = ContactModelForm()
        return render(request, 'contact/contact_us.html', {'forms': form})
```

You can also improve the view by working with a `CreateView` in this case:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView


class ContactView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'contact/contact_us.html'
    form_class = ContactModelForm
    success_urls = reverse_lazy('home')
```

This will pass the form to the template as `form`, not <s>`forms`</s>.

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem has not been solved yet. I can contact you through Telegram

Comment: @Mohammad: are you sure you make a POST request, can you see the request in the *server* console?

Comment: Willem, When an empty form is sent from the HTML side, the post method instead of sending the form to be filled. An empty form is received from the condition of what to do if valid, it is rejected because the form is empty until now, right after that, when it has to render the form. The browser page freezes and the post method error is not allowed in the terminal. And the code returns 200